# Wirelessly connect laptop sound (Linux Mint) to Desktop PC (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, audio, linux-mint, bluetooth

I'd like to watch Netflix on my Laptop and have the sound output done over the sound system that is connected to my desktop PC. How can I realize this wirelessly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the laptop's Bluetooth output to an adapter, e.g. [iCrius](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071WR8GNZ) or [Riversong](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07GSQS9RD). Depending on the speakers, you might need a 3.5mm female-female (jack) connector. If your laptop doesn't have built in Bluetooth connectivity, then add a [USB to Bluetooth adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009ZIILLI).

Comment: The female-female cable implies I need unplug the stereo system from my computer. I'm looking for a solution where I can reroute the incoming bluetooth signal to the already available output. Is this possible with the devices you recommended?

Comment: Nope, use a Y-adapter. https://www.amazon.com/Kingtop-Adapter-Tablet-Headsets-Version/dp/B01I3A47I4 .Y not?

Comment: Bear in mind that this is likely to have a high latency & I'm not sure how you would compensate for that with a streaming service such as Netflix... it would be easy with local file playback on something like VLC, but streaming is inherently different. I've never tried VLC on a streaming service, so can only speculate that it might be able to handle it as it does for a local file. You will need something that can delay the picture so it matches back to the sound. Once you've worked out the latency it would be fairly simple to dial in the same number each time [assuming no BT drift].